# How to retrieve data from json using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json

How can I use ng-repeat to retrieve the EmpName of EmpId :2 from category :1.And how to get categoryName from this json object.

Here I'm pushing the allItems data into items array.Similarly,how can I get the data from category :2

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Myjson:

```
$scope.items = [];
        $scope.allItems = [{

        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryName": "abc",
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 1,
            "EmpName": "Raj",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }],
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 2,
            "EmpName": "sai",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryName": "xyz",
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 1,
            "EmpNameName": "Sita",
            "EmpJob": "Software Engineer",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }],
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 2,
            "EmpName": "sathya",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }]

}]
```

My html:

```
 <div id="Div1" ng-repeat="item in items">
                                <div id="headerDiv3" style="margin-top: 35px;">
                                    <div id="titleDiv3"><font color="white">{{item.Employee[0].EmpName}}</font></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="valuesDiv3">
                                    <div id="yearDiv3"><font color="white">{{item.Employee[0].year}} </font></div>
                                    <div id="salaryDiv3"><font color="white">{{item.Employee[0].salary}}</font></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data from nested json object using ng-repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253033/how-to-retrieve-data-from-nested-json-object-using-ng-repeat)

Comment: Ya,I'm able to get the data from empId:1 but unable to get the data from empId:2.can u please help me out ..

Answer (score 0):

First of all , your JSON array is not correct, it should be like --

```
 $scope.allItems = [{

        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryName": "abc",
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 1,
            "EmpName": "Raj",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }],
       {
            "EmpId": 2,
            "EmpName": "sai",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }],
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryName": "xyz",
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 1,
            "EmpNameName": "Sita",
            "EmpJob": "Software Engineer",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }],
       {
            "EmpId": 2,
            "EmpName": "sathya",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }]

}]
```

Now you have to iterate twice first for `allItems` and second for `allItems.Employee`.

In html:

```
<div id="Div1" ng-repeat="items in allItems" >
     <div id="Div2" ng-repeat="item in items.Employee>
          <div id="Div3"><font color="white">{{item.EmpName}}</font></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The json data provided was not correct. Since 'Employee' is a list, so its contents must be within an array, but it was getting repeated. Moreover, the name is not uniform as 'EmpNameName', is present, I guess it is data due to spell mistake in place of  'EmpName'.

Please find the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/6h5xneke/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <div id="Div1" ng-repeat="item in allItems">
        <div id="Div2" ng-repeat="emp in item.Employee">
            <div id="Div3">
                <font color="white">{{emp.EmpName}}</font>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope){
        $scope.allItems = [{
        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryName": "abc",
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 1,
            "EmpName": "Raj",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        },
        {
            "EmpId": 2,
            "EmpName": "sai",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryName": "xyz",
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 1,
            "EmpName": "Sita",
            "EmpJob": "Software Engineer",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        },
        {
            "EmpId": 2,
            "EmpName": "sathya",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }]    
    }];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work for you with correct JSON format as shown bellow.

```
 <div id="Div1" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{categoryId:1}" >
       <div id="Div2"  ng-repeat="emp in item.Employee| filter:{EmpId:2}">
            <div id="Div3"><font color="white">{{emp.EmpName}}</font></div>
       </div>
</div>


$scope.allItems = [{
        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryName": "abc",
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 1,
            "EmpName": "Raj",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        },
        {
            "EmpId": 2,
            "EmpName": "sai",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryName": "xyz",
        "Employee": [{
            "EmpId": 1,
            "EmpName": "Sita",
            "EmpJob": "Software Engineer",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        },
        {
            "EmpId": 2,
            "EmpName": "sathya",
            "EmpJob": "Accounts",
            "DataList": [{
                "year": "Oct-2015",
                "salary": "244"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jul-2015",
                "salary": "100"
            },
            {
                "year": "Jun-2015",
                "salary": "117"
            }]
        }]    
    }];
```